# Numpy - creating matrix

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, numpy, matrix

I would want to create this matrix:

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

I can easily get the identity matrix by doing

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.eye((10))
```

Comment: smells somehow like homework?

Comment: Why do you want to use `for` loop particularly? `numpy` is generally good for *avoiding* explicit loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `k` argument of `eye` to set the index of the diagonal :

```
>>> m1= np.eye((10))
>>> m2= np.eye((10),k=1)
>>> m3 = np.eye((10),k=-1)
>>> m1+m2+m3
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Or :

```
>>> np.triu(np.tril(np.ones((10,10)),k=1),k=-1)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: I like to hear about the reason of down vote!

Comment: I think you got downvoted because the OP asked for a loop. Not sure why he wants it.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor its not a good reason for down vote at all because,  mayhap OP thought that its the only way!

Comment: I agree...  Who knows why he asked that

Answer (score 0):

Knock yourself out

```
n = 10
[[1. if (row == 0 and col in (0, 1)) or
        (row == n-1 and col in (n-2, n-1)) or
        (row not in (0, n-1) and col in (row-1, row, row+1))
     else 0. for col in range(n)] for row in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with standart python library elements, the problem can be solved as this:

iterate over matrix (list of sublists).

1. for the first row (first list) flip second element to 1.
2. for the last row flip the element.
3. before the last one to 1
4. for rest of rows.
5. find the index of 1 and assign it to  value.
6. flip the element on the right and left to 1.

   for row in matrix:

   ```
   if row == matrix[0]:
       row[1]=1

   elif row == matrix[len(matrix)-1]:
       row[len(row)-2] = 1

   else:
       p= row.index(1)
       row[p-1], row[p+1] = 1,1
   ```

Comment: I think it's always good practice to include some written description or explanation of your code.